# Select query dynamically from matrix linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to check if Value matches any of the table headers and then pick first value of that column. Lets say i already picked out what row im at, now i need to see which columnheader matches my value and then pick the value of that column and that row.

```
  A B C D E
1 X X X X X
2 X X X X X
3 X X X X X
4 X X X X X
```

I have been using LINQ but havent got it working correctly yet

So to make this simple, i already got the rowvalue lets say 1, and if for example my (Value = C) then i want to pick out just that value and write to string. Someone can help me out? Thanks in advance.

I would like to replace this....

```
 if (Type.Equals("A"))
                    Type = query.First().a;
                else if (Type.Equals("B"))
                    Type = query.First().b;
                else if (Type.Equals("C"))
                    Type = query.First().c;
                else if (Type.Equals("D"))
                    Type = query.First().d;
```

I guess i have to be using Reflection to get this solved but i got no idea how to get this working...

Comment: Are rows and collums arrays or what?

Comment: Do you need to get the ColumnNames dynamically or do you know them before hand?

Comment: Its matrix, and i know what the column names are before hand

Comment: What data structure it the matrix? An example of how the matrix is constructed would be helpful.

Comment: if you say about reflection see: [GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx), and  [GetProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy(v=vs.110).aspx), some thing like: `var first = query.First(); Type = first.GetType().GetProperty(TypeName).GetValue(first)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var item = query.First();
    string key = "A";

    var p = item.GetType().GetProperty(key.ToLower());
    var type = (Type)p.GetValue(item, null);
```

Comment: Im not getting the correct string value back, but i think thats almost how i should be doing this.